# Sentinel2 level 2A products

Tags: sentinel-2

Is there any link form where I can download Sentinel 2 Level 2A products for Asian Countries or it has to be done through Sentinel Toolbox only?

Comment: With a bit of luck [EO Browser](https://www.sentinel-hub.com/apps/eo_browser) may have L2A products for your area of interest.

Comment: Thanks Kazuhito, but no luck on finding L2A image on EO Browser for Asia.

Answer (score 2):

The production of Sentinel-2 Level-2A products is currently limited to the Euro-Mediterranean region. So to get L2A products for images outside this region it is recommended to use the Sen2Cor tool. [Here is the relevant scihub news article.](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/news/News00305)

Answer (score 0):

If for scientific/private research, you can also use [scihub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/) for free, you only have to create an account. There are two downsides: First you have to search for cloudfree pictures yourself, and sometimes the servers are really unstable, meaning you might have to start downloads several times anew.

As to how far the data covers Asia, I do not know. Yet, Sentinel 2 2a data is available.

Comment: Thanks Erik, but thats available only for European region.